# SQL Join , eliminate duplicate results

Tags: sql, join

I have the following Join statement  :

```
SELECT DISTINCT dn.fname, dn.lname,w.websit,q.qual,q.year,q.postqual,p.pnumber,a.accred,n.nspecial
FROM cur_doctor_names dn
LEFT JOIN cur_website w ON dn.userid = w.userid
LEFT JOIN cur_qualification q ON dn.userid = q.userid
LEFT JOIN (Select * from cur_phone_numbers where type="primary") p On dn.userid = p.userid
Left JOIN cur_accreditation a On dn.userid = a.userid
Left JOIN cur_niche n On dn.userid = n.userid
WHERE dn.userid =69
GROUP BY p.pnumber
```

For tables cur_phone_numbers (p) , cur_accreditation(a) , cur_niche (n) the result can contain from 0 to 3 records for a user , the result that I am getting currently gives me all possible combinations for the data . I tried using group by on the columns individually but that eliminates results from the other columns . I dont mind getting a result with nulls . This is the result I am getting currently  :

```
fname         lname        website  qual  year  postqual    pnumber  accred    nspecial
===========================================================================================
First Doctor  Last Doctor  NULL     NULL  NULL  NULL        123      ISO 9001  one
First Doctor  Last Doctor  NULL     NULL  NULL  NULL        123      ISO 9001  two
First Doctor  Last Doctor  NULL     NULL  NULL  NULL        123      ISO       one
First Doctor  Last Doctor  NULL     NULL  NULL  NULL        123      ISO       two
First Doctor  Last Doctor  NULL     NULL  NULL  NULL        1234     ISO 9001  one
First Doctor  Last Doctor  NULL     NULL  NULL  NULL        1234     ISO 9001  two
First Doctor  Last Doctor  NULL     NULL  NULL  NULL        1234     ISO       one
First Doctor  Last Doctor  NULL     NULL  NULL  NULL        1234     ISO       two
```

Comment: based on the data you provided, it is not duplicate  data.  The last 3 columns `pnumber`, `accred`, `nspecial` show distinct values for each row.  If you only want one value, then you need to decide which one you want to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to choose one of the value using `aggregate functions`, for example `max`:

```
SELECT dn.fname, dn.lname,w.websit,q.qual,q.year,q.postqual,max(p.pnumber),max(a.accred),max(n.nspecial)
FROM cur_doctor_names dn
LEFT JOIN cur_website w ON dn.userid = w.userid
LEFT JOIN cur_qualification q ON dn.userid = q.userid
LEFT JOIN (Select * from cur_phone_numbers where type="primary") p On dn.userid = p.userid
Left JOIN cur_accreditation a On dn.userid = a.userid
Left JOIN cur_niche n On dn.userid = n.userid
WHERE dn.userid =69
GROUP BY p.pnumber
```